# using web page variable for google analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I am very much new to google analytics. I have a page level variable will have either zero or greater than 0. If it is zero then different db query will be executed and if it is greater than zero different db query will be executed on the same page which does not have any java script.  Is it possible to get these actions in google analytics.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

you need to place the Google Analytics (Java script) code in the head of the HTML document. once you do that, you can track these actions by using event tracking. Execute the Event Tracking Function in the database call position.

Event Tracking : https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/eventTrackerGuide